# Options error: Unrecognized option or missing or extra parameter(s) in client.ovpn:88: ca (2.5.6)

Tags: openvpn

Im Using openvpn to build a vpn between two PCs
when I run Connect the this error is shown:

```
Options error: Unrecognized option or missing or extra parameter(s) in client.ovpn:88: ca (2.5.6)
```

my code:

```
# file can be used for all clients.

ca "C:\\Program Files\\OpenVPN\\config\\ca.crt"

cert "C:\\Program Files\\OpenVPN\\config\\client.crt"

key "C:\\Program Files\\OpenVPN\\config\\client.key"
```

Comment: sometimes we need to check if or not the file uses expected EOL (end of line).